# Ping doesn't work

Tags: android, wifi, ping

I want to scan my local network with my application, so I tried to ping all local IP but my code work only for the local IP of my android device.

This is my function :

```
int timeout=10000;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        String host = "192.168.1." + i;
        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
                System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                Log.i("host", host);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output : "host: 192.168.1.10" This is the Local IP of my device.

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="...">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are wrong

`String host = "192.168.1." + i;` /* You missed the dot(.) symbol after 1 */

You should move these three lines above application. It should should like below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @Error404, then everything should work. I just tested the code. It is working on my PC.

Comment: int timeout = 1000; /* I decreased the timeout value */
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            String host = "192.168.1." + i;
            try {
                if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
                    System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: @Error404, which Android OS version are you using? From after 6.0, Android by default uses ART (Android Runtime) based permission.

Comment: I'm on version 5.1.

Comment: I already tested your code after you move uses-permission lines above application, it becomes Everything correct. Please look in detail your code. I don't see any wrong there. Also you cal accept my answer.

Comment: I moved those three line but the problem persist. Did I need to be root on my device ?

Comment: No, please send me whole project zip in infofuniversities@gmail.com. I definitely help you.

Comment: After some new tests, my code detect the device itself and the gateway but not computers placed behind. Is it normal ?